# Changing a field type with a migration

Tags: postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an `Info` table with a `age` field which is an `int`

But I want to change the type to a `date` so that I can calculate the age dynamically.

So I did this migration :

```
class ChangeDateFormatInInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    change_column :infos, :age, :date
  end
end
```

But there was a `DatatypeMismatch`

```
column "age" cannot be cast automatically to type date
```

So I changed it to :

```
change_column :infos, :age, :date, 'USING age::date'
```

But it still gives me

```
migrateTypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

I don't really get it, I'm telling it to convert it, so what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first remove the column and then add it again with new datatype.

So try below code:

```
rails g migration ChangeDateFormatInInfo
```

then goto `db/migrate/change_date_format_in_info_xxxx.rb` file and open it.

Add below code in migration file:

```
class ChangeDateFormatInInfo < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column :infos, :age
    add_column :infos, :age, :date
  end
end
```

then run command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't thought about it, I just did a migration to drop the field, and another one to add a field. Done now :)

```
rails g migration remove_age_from_info age:integer

rails g migration add_age_to_info age:date
```